# Java terminal emulator

Tags: java, terminal-emulator, vt100

Does anyone knows of a library or a class that emulates the vt100 terminal (doesn't matter if graphical or not). What I want basically is a class that implements the logic of a vt100 terminal (like when receiving a "delete" code will call a delete function, or if GUI based that will delete one char).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Telnetd seems to be a complete and pretty well documented solution:

http://telnetd.sourceforge.net/

You can also try:

http://www.jcraft.com/jcterm/

It behaves like a VT100 and uses a SSH2 connection. But the website indicates the VT100 emulation is incomplete.

Comment: Telnetd is a server. It doesn't do terminal emulation. Telnet clients do that.

Comment: @EJP: You're wrong.This is not a standalone application, but a library, and it contains everything needed to create both a server and a client.

Answer (score 6):

Have a look at the JediTerm project: https://github.com/JetBrains/jediterm

It has both graphical implementation as well as API to override. 
Graphical version works for remote SSH connections(using JSch) and local pty(using [Pty4J](https://github.com/JetBrains/pty4j)).

It is a mature project used for the embedded terminal in JetBrains products.